# What are the self destructs in buying erc20 token

Tags: bsc, selfdestruct

I know some cases for use self destruction but I can't understand the purpose in the transactions of this [sandwich bot](https://bscscan.com/tx/0xc794cb34c88be91ef586385c897a80c0b49f5657c4e7485bd8afbeccadf99e57)
I saw other cases of sandwich bots using self destruction in your transactions but I can't understand the purpose about in this case

If you understand can you explain me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but my guess is utilization of *gas tokens*.

Gas tokens are tokens which are used as a way of "storing" gas when gas prices are low and utilizing the gas when gas prices are high. They work by deploying a contract (costs gas) and when you want to "utilize" the gas in some future transaction, you selfdestruct that contract. Deleting data from the blockchain releases some gas, so your transaction's gas usage goes down due to the selfdestruct.

Ethereum blockchain made gas tokens useless some time ago by a soft fork, but the BSC blockchain still has gas tokens.

So the transaction selfdestructs some contracts to reduce the transaction's overall gas usage.